# How to sort item in each category in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
if params[:category].blank?
  @items = Item.all.order("created_at DESC")
else
  @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
  @items = Item.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
end

if params[:foodtype].blank?
  @items = Item.all.order("created_at DESC")
else
  @food_type_id = FoodType.find_by(name: params[:foodtype]).id
  @items = Item.where(food_type_id: @food_type_id).order("created_at DESC")
end

if params[:ethniccuisine].blank?
  @items = Item.all.order("created_at DESC")
else
  @ethnic_cuisine_id = EthnicCuisine.find_by(name: params[:ethniccuisine]).id
  @items = Item.where(ethnic_cuisine_id: @ethnic_cuisine_id).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Currently only items in EthinicCuisine is sortable. How to display items that belongs to any of the categories?